# Properties of a different kind of a logarithm

Tags: logarithms

We all have heard about the natural logarithm for any number. Basically we all know that the natural logarithm is the logarithm to the base of $e$,which is a transcendental number. Now what about the other transcendental numbers such as $\pi$ . How would the logarithm to the base of $\pi$ behave. By behave I mean how will the graph of this kind of a logarithm look like,what will be its properties?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that all logarithmic curves 'look' and behave the same. They only differ by a scalar factor. For example:

$$\text{If } y = \pi^x\text{, then  we want}\log_\pi(\cdot)\text{ such that }x = \log_\pi{y}$$
$$\text{But }y = \pi^x = e^{\ln(\pi)x}\text{, so } x = \frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(\pi)}$$
Putting this together:
$$\log_\pi(x) = \frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(\pi)}$$
Where $\ln(x)$ is the 'natural' logarithm. This property hold for all Real $c>0$ as an exponential base.

Comment: Technically you need positive $c$.

Comment: @jameselmore but what if the base is not real for eg $i$ then what will happen to the logarithm

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay, I'm afraid I do not have enough experience with the logarithm of a complex number to be able to give an accurate explanation. I can imagine that the result will be similar to the one above, the question becomes what corrections or modifications are needed to the $\ln$ function such that we can calculate $\ln(i)$

Comment: Seeing as I answered your original question, could you kindly accept this answer?